# Как определить переменную внутри цикла v-for (Vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Мне нужно вывести в цикле шаблона данные обработанные функцией multiply(), а чтобы не выводить их через `{{multiply(n)}}`, что будет вызывать функцию несколько раз с одними и теми же данными, хочу определить переменную `n2`, в которой будут лежать обработанные данные.

Как это можно сделать?

Наваял пример (неработающий):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  template: `
 <div>
  <div v-for="n in arr">
   <div :n2="multiply(n)">
    <span>*{{n2}}*{{n2}}*{{n2}}*</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 `,
  methods: {
    multiply: function(x) {
      return x * 2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Пример на [codepen](http://codepen.io/anme/pen/qrZgYg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вариант [v-bind](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) (`:n2="multiply(n)"`) скорей подходит для *передачи переменной* в компонент (если точнее, то компонент будет *следить* за изменением `n2`)

Например, создадим компонент `multiply`:

```js
Vue.component('multiply', {
  template: `
     <div>
            <div>
                <span>*{{n2}}*{{n2}}*{{n2}}*</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  props: ['n2']
});


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  template: `
 <div>
      <multiply v-for="n in arr" :n2="multiply(n)"></multiply>
 </div>
 `,
  methods: {
    multiply: function(x) {
      return x * 2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Также, как вариант, формировать содержимое `span` непосредственно методом `multiply`. А уже в `span` помещать результат с помощью директивы [v-text](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  template: `
 <div>
  <div v-for="(n, index) in arr">
   <div>
    <span v-text="multiply(arr[index])"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 `,
  methods: {
    multiply: function(x) {
      return `*${(x * 2)}*${(x * 2)}*${(x * 2)}*`;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо:

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in arr">
    <div>
        <span v-text="multiply(arr[index])"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Лучше:

```
<div v-for="n in arr">
    <div>
        <span v-text="multiply(n)"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```